# IBM Worklight 5 - iOS app shows white screen on second launch

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm having a problem with a hybrid app for iOS which I have written using Worklight 5. The problem is that the application only runs properly the first time it is launched, and after being closed in multi-tasking and relaunched, the app will not open properly and instead displays a white screen. The only way to get the application to run again is to delete it from the device completely and then re-install it.

This behaviour is the same in the iPad simulator and on a physical iPad.

I don't have any code to provide as all of the Objective-C is generated by Worklight and all I have written is the HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript and I think that's unlikely to be affecting it. Has anybody else experienced this issue and if so is there a way to resolve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Is it a crash? Anything from crash logs? Never heard of Worklight before, do they have inline logging...Go old style and log inside function to check which one is causing an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the behavior sounds to me much more inline with changing the name of the HTML file itself and in application-descriptor.xml's `mainFile` element. Have you touched these? If yes, then you also need to change the name of the application's folder.

Comment: That was the problem, I'd renamed the main HTML file - changed it back and it's fixed. I thought just changing it in the application descriptor would be enough... so is there another step I have to take if I want to rename the main HTML file?

Comment: As mentioned, if you insist on changing the application's HTML filename, you need to change: the filename, the value of mainFaile in application-descriptor.xml and the FOLDER name of the application under the apps folder.

Comment: Oh ok - thanks for your advice, I don't really need to change the name of the HTML file, I was just wondering why there was an option to change it in the application descriptor if it doesn't work. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to try:

1. Open `cordova.js` inside the Xcode project.
2. Replace: `execXhr.open('HEAD', "/!gap_exec", true);`
3. With `execXhr.open('HEAD', "/!gap_exec?" + +new Date, true);`.

It's from [a fix](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-js.git;a=commitdiff;h=ba7edf04ba6403588ba22995c0b9b62d58ceeca8;hp=099a51d157bf9bfcb112075f5406453504f40d72) that was applied to Cordova 2.4. It *adds a timestamp to the query param to prevent caching*.

No idea if that will help, it sounds *vaguely* familiar to an issue I ran into.